# Reference object variable in Bicep template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I'm currently trying to manually convert an existing ARM template to bicep because the automated decompile method fails.

The existing template contains the following variables:

```
"environmentSize": {
        "dev": "small",
        "msdn": "small",
        "int": "small",
        "act": "large",
        "prod": "large"
    },
    "size": "[variables('environmentSize')[parameters('environment')]]",
```

What would be the equivalent with Bicep?

I've tried the following but it's clearly wrong as I get a red squiggly below the $:

```
var environmentSize = {
  dev:'small'
  msdn:'small'
  int:'small'
  act:'large'
  prod:'large'
}
var size = environmentSize.${environment}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using brackets notation should work.

```bicep
param environment string = 'dev'

var environmentSize = {
  dev:'small'
  msdn:'small'
  int:'small'
  act:'large'
  prod:'large'
}

output size string = environmentSize[environment]
```